# How to run gmic from command line cmd windows gimp

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-prompt, gimp, gmic

I am looking up on the Internet for hours and can't get to how to execute a command on the command prompt that does something out of gimp files and furthermore get to apply filters to images with gmic, I managed to do it all well with Image Magick, using the convert command, it just works, but for gmic I try on cmd

```
  gimp -b -
```

as stated on their website's documentation: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

But no, it pops:

'gimp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Am I asking something very dumb, I really don't know what I am doing wrong, maybe I am missing some steps, the error gives me a clue as if I had to create a file for the gimp command to work other than have succesfully installed it in Windows.

I'm on Windows 8 64 bit by the way. Enterprise edition.

Thanks very much for any help.

Gimp installed 2.8.2
gmic installed 1.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line interface does not know where `gimp` is all by itself. Either call it with the full path, something like `C:\Program Files\Gimp\gimp.exe -b -`, or add the directory that contains gimp to your `%PATH%` system variable.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is only to apply a G'MIC effect on an image, why not using the command-line interface 'gmic' of the G'MIC project, instead of trying doing that through the plug-in for GIMP ? The G'MIC project provides a command-line interface 'gmic' for his tool, so it should be less difficult to use I guess + you won't have the limitations due to GIMP (8bits processing e.g, as 'gmic' is able to process 16bits images).